# Field trace used to show certain elements are not in certain fields or extension of fields

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, trace, field-trace

[These notes](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.643.7185&rep=rep1&type=pdf) from the Uni. Connecticut state about finite extensions of fields that *"among elementary applications, the field trace can be used to show certain numbers are not in certain fields"*, but follow up discussion does not delve much into this concept.

Edit:

I got in touch with the author of the notes who kindly updated the document. There are referenced examples inside on Section 4 which show how the field trace can be used in such a way. Still it remains to be generalised for other cases, e.g. prime finite field examples or cases over binary extension fields:

How can the trace of an element $e \in L/K$, L over K, reflect participation (or not) in the field extension $L$? I come from an engineering background so can someone please explain in summary why this holds and provide an example? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. You say yourself that the notes now contain an example of precisely that (and indeed they do). I'm not sure what more you expect, there is no general statement, it's more like in specific cases you can try to say "if $e\in L$, then given what $e$ looks like, then $Tr_{L/K}(e)$ should have such and such property, but actually here it's impossible, so $e$ cannot be in $L$". And you have examples in the notes.

Comment: The concept I had in mind (which indeed is not reflected correctly) is whether this concept can (and how) generalise over prime Galois fields, but yes as you state I think this cannot generalise in every case and is more like circumstantial so I will probably delete the question.